# Internet problems

Tags: windows-xp, internet

I've got problems on my freshly installed windows Xp machine. I cannot connect to the internet and I've tried various 'solutions' provided to me by the help and support center. Surprisingly none of them worked...

Anyways, I've got 3 pc's next to me sharing a lan which is connected to the internet though a modem. The computer I use right now uses windows xp aswell and runs without any problems. I've tried everything on not working computer.

I've ran the connection wizard several times, but it's not working :(

Also I've very little experience with this version of windows, so I'm sorry if the solution is obvious.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more detail as to what you've already tried?  The simple solution is 'look at the configuration for the connection on a working machine and manually change this one to match' but I have to think they already had you do that...

Comment: So this isn't an internet problem. Your connection works if you are able to get out on other machines. This is a router or a computer problem if just one computer can't get out. What type of router? are you using DHCP or static assignment? Does your computer show up in the arp table?

Comment: What happens when you open a command prompt (>Start>Run>type "cmd">OK) and type "ipconfig /all"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using modem to connect ? Make sure you've already installed it's driver.
Or are you using LAN (cable) or Wifi? Also make sure that your lan and wireless device have driver installed .

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting TCP/IP:

http://www.petri.co.il/reinstall_tcp_ip_on_windows_xp.htm